# Continuous functions on topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a function and we call this a continuous function if for every open set $V$ in $Y$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$. But where did we get the idea of function having an inverse? Is it implicitly assumed? What about $f^{-1}(Y)$? Will that be $X$? In one theorem in Munkres when we assume for every closed set $B$ in $Y$, $f^{-1}(B)$ is a closed subset of $X$, in the case can we say $f^{-1}(Y)$ is $X$?

Answer (score 1):

We got the idea of $f^{-1}(V)$ by needing notation and terminology for the idea of "the set of all points $x \in X$ such that $f(x) \in V$". In particular, when $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, in the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity of $f$ at a point $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ you encounter the set of all points $x$ such that $f(x) \in (f(x_0)-\epsilon,f(x_0)+\epsilon)$, and you learn that this subset contains $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ for some $\delta$.

As for what this has to do with inverse, imagine the special case that $f : X \to Y$ is a bijection and $V=\{y\}$ is a single point. The inverse function $f^{-1} : Y \to X$ would be defined, and $x=f^{-1}(y)$ would be the unique point in the set $f^{-1}(V)$.

But for general purposes we need this even for functions that are not one-to-one and for subsets $V \subset Y$ consisting of more than a single point (such as $V = (f(x_0)-\epsilon,f(x_0)+\epsilon)$).

Answer (score 0):

We define
$$
f^{-1}(A) = \{x \in X| f(x) \in A\}
$$
for any $A \subseteq Y$. Once $f$ is defined, so will be images of subsets of $X$ into $Y$ and preimages of subsets of $Y$ in $X$.